# Understanding R lm function (weighted) – "coefficients not defined due to singularities"

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, weighted-regression

I'm working on generating a weighted linear model in R using the `lm` function. My dataset has about 1200 observations. My independent variables are a set of 168 principal components, i.e., the independent variables have already been normalized and are uncorrelated. There are no factor variables. The weights vector has values ranging from about 0.05 to 0.2.

My issue is that when I create a model using all 168 independent variables, I get a message that 22 of them are not defined due to singularities. My # of observations is much greater than the number of variables, so I am having difficulty grasping why this would happen. Others who posted about this same warning message found solutions that related to multicollinearity or factor variables, which does not really apply to my situation.

Thanks very much for any ideas! Here's the output (the curweight column is the weights as I specified above):

```
pc_string <- "log_hire_length ~ PC_1 + PC_2 + PC_3 + ... + PC_168"

Call:
lm(formula = formula(pc_string), data = train, weights = train[, 
    curweight])

Weighted Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.15762 -0.16307  0.03723  0.24849  1.16929 

Coefficients: (22 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.214563   0.051896 119.750   <2e-16 ***
PC_1        -0.031482   0.318851  -0.099   0.9214    
PC_2        -0.280412   1.682352  -0.167   0.8677    
PC_3        -0.315965   1.053582  -0.300   0.7643    
...

PC_145       0.184415   2.946271   0.063   0.9501    
PC_146       0.468855   2.919797   0.161   0.8725    
PC_147             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_148             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_149             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_150             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_151             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_152             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_153             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_154             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_155             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_156             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_157             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_158             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_159             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_160             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_161             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_162             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_163             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_164             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_165             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_166             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_167             NA         NA      NA       NA    
PC_168             NA         NA      NA       NA    

Residual standard error: 0.4434 on 1123 degrees of freedom
  (8 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Comment: Even though you assert that they're uncorrelated, nevertheless, what does the cholesky decomposition (or SVD) of X'X, or the little-R part of QR decomposition of X look like? In particular, what are the diagonals of the cholesky factor, or of the sigma-matrix or of the R at elements between 140 and 150 or so?